# How do I get Labels and TextButtons to overlay bodies?

Tags: android, button, label, libgdx, box2d

Right now, I have bodies, Labels, and TextButtons in my Box2D world. The problem is that the labels and buttons show up in a table after the bodies are already placed in the world and when they show up, the bodies are on top of them and then you can't see the labels and buttons. How can I make the labels and buttons appear on top of the bodies? I can display code upon request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean the buttons and labels of your game HUD or user-interface which always should be rendered on top of the bodies and actors?

A box2d body itself doesn't have a texture/actor/image or whatever, unless you connect it... And I hope you're not connecting your labels etc with the bodies, only if you actually want the buttons to behave physically... ;)

So if you just want to always render the buttons etc on top of the whole scene just use a second `Stage` (or a second SpriteBatch) that calls its `draw()` method after the scene and bodies has been rendered... This way, they will always be on top of everything else and you can use a different coordinate system for scene and HUD...

Hope it helps...

Comment: thank so much. it worked by putting the stage.draw(); at the bottom of the render loop

Comment: @Mercify always think about the rendering order. If you are rendering in 2D the things you `draw()` as the last appear on top, while the others get overdrawn. In `scene2d` you can use the z-index to sort things, but it is not sure that it works, as it only sorts a list, depending on this z-Index.

Comment: The z-order in scene2d is just by group. Basically you can sort groups/actors on the stage however you want, and then in one group if you have several items, you can order those. For creating HUDs or alike, this is not recommended though... Also, you will never be able to draw an element of one group on top of an element of another group, if that other group has a higher z-index in the parent level.